# Why is an action query not working in access VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I tested an UPDATE query in Access's query design, and it works, but when I try to use it in my module, I get the error:

**Invalid SQL statement; expected... or 'UPDATE'.**

My query:

```
strSql = "UPDATE " & rs.Fields("tableName") & _ 
" SET " & rs.Fields("foreignKeyName") & " = " & rsContacts.Fields("contactId") & _ 
" WHERE contactId = " & ContactID
```

- **rs:** a table that has tableName, foriegnKeyName of the tables to update
- **rsContacts:** a list of contactIds (*currently standing on a particular one*).

The actual string comes out like this:

```
    UPDATE myTable SET ContactId = 5 WHERE contactId = 2
```

If the query works, and it **is** an action query, why am I getting this error?

This is my full code:

```vb
Public Sub updateChildTables(ByVal ContactID As Long, ByVal CompanyID As Long)
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rsPending As Recordset

    strSql = "SELECT contactID FROM contacts _
              WHERE companyId = " & CompanyID & " and contactId <> " & ContactID
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        strSql = "SELECT * FROM childTables"
        Set rsChild = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
        rsChild.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rsChild.EOF
            strSql = "UPDATE " & rsChild.Fields("tableName") & " SET " & rsChild.Fields("foreignKeyName") & " = " & rs.Fields("contactId") & " WHERE contactId = " & ContactID
            DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
            rs.moveNext
        Loop
        rsChild.Close
        Set rsChild = Nothing
    End If
```

Comment: This happens a lot when data has ' . Can You check if there are any single quotes?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code, including the command that executes it and the SQL from the query?

Comment: @JanWalczak, I can't see any.

Comment: @Hambone, You're right. I completely forgot to do that. I updated the question now.

Comment: Is it really necessary to create that statement generically? Depending on data-types it will be a never ending source of problems, if you just concatenate a statement like this... You might use parameters or use the recordset and its abilities to change data. Please show the code where you execute this command...

Comment: Indulge me here...  if you take the query string, ` UPDATE myTable SET ContactId = 5 WHERE contactId = 2` and create a brand new query (in the designer), go to the SQL View, paste that in and run it, it works okay?  I'm wondering, for example, if `contactId` is a Primary Key and you are creating a duplicate by changing the value of 2 to 5 (maybe there already is a 5)?  It doesn't match the error message, but they don't always do.  And am I right that `contactId` and `ContactId` are the same field?

Comment: @Shnugo, Yes, it is necessary. The code really is to complicated to show here. I tried to simplify it. But I can tell  you that "tableName" is a short string, and the contactIds are longs.

Comment: @MJH How are you calling this? Are you creating a *querydef-object*? do you use `.Execute` and if yes: from which object? How are you dealing with quotes, floats or datetime values, if your fields are not int? Might there be fields or table names with blanks or forbidden characters?

Comment: @Hambone, **1.** Yes, it works in SQL view (Query Design). **2.** **contactId** in **myTable** is not a primary key. **3.** **contactId** is the long field in myTable, and **ContactId** is a VBA long variable that  = 2.

Comment: I give up. I pasted the code, and I hope it's clear enough. I did try to simplify it a little, but I'm afraid it's still not clear to somone who doesn't know my database... I hope you guys can figure this out.

Comment: I must admit; everything looks fine.  I have an idea that might help debug.  It's not an answer, but I'll have to post it as one since it's too long for a comment

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print strSql` before `DoCmd.RunSQL strSql`. Ctrl+G shows the output. Does the error occur on every record? If not, add the specific UPDATE statement where the error happens. And please add the **actual** SQL you are executing, not simplified ("myTable"). --- Is the message at the top of your question the **full** error message?

Comment: What's the name of actual table or fields? Just a suggestion but if they are [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) try square brackets around identifiers and especially if such identifiers have spaces or symbols: `UPDATE [myTable] SET [ContactId] = 5 WHERE [contactId] = 2`.

Comment: @HansUp, That's true. I had that bug in my code when I pasted it here. I fixed it though some time ago... Thanks, though that's not the cause of my problem. I'll fix it here too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my idea for debugging and possibly even resolving this.

Create a query from within Access normally -- name it `UpdateMyTable`, for the sake of this example.

Then, rather than using the `DoCmd`, actually execute this specific query from your VBA.

```
Dim qry As QueryDef

strSql = "UPDATE " & rsChild.Fields("tableName") & " SET " & _
    rsChild.Fields("foreignKeyName") & " = " & _
    rs.Fields("contactId") & " WHERE contactId = " & ContactID

Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("UpdateMyTable")
qry.SQL = strSql
qry.Execute
```

The big advantage of this is that you can very easily debug this from within Access to both see the rendered SQL and manually run it / tweak it.